# numpy array filtering twice and replace

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering, slice

I want to execute two filtering and one replacing steps on a large array but I cannot figure a way to do it efficiently without making some copy or for loop.

Example, imagine two numpy arrays of different sizes. I want to apply two filters. The first one to select only elements of b that are inferior to 6  (b') and a second filters to replace the values of b' by the values of a if a is inferior to b':

```
a = np.array( [ 2,2,2,2,2,2] )
b = np.array( [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] )
```

I apply a first masking by selecting the elements of b inferior to 6 :

```
m = b < 6
```

Now, I want to replace the value of b[m] by the minimal value between a and b[m], with expected results in b :

```
[ 0,1,2,2,2,2,6,7,8,9]
```

Using :

```
n = a < b[m]
b[m][n] = a[n]
```

doesn't work. Probably because of some intermediate array. With

```
c = np.array( [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  ] )
```

I can directly do :

```
c[ a < c ] = a [ a < c ]
```

and it works. Any cool slicing way to do it without making secondary array ?
Thanks.

Comment: [`numpy.where()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) could be useful here, possibly nested...

Comment: I just found a way : b [ b[b < 6] > a  ] = a [ b[ b < 6 ] > a  ]
but it's not really elegant. Any better idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = b < 6 
b[m] = np.where(b[m]< a,b[m],a)
```